# Change Facebook Site URL after APP approved?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Facebook App and have entered a Facebook Site URL.

I would be submitting my Facebook App for approval soon.

My question is this: 
After my app has been approved, would it be ok to change the Site URL i.e. the APP would not have its permission revoked by Facebook?

My reason for the change in site-url in future is that while I am deploying on Amazon right now, but after 6 months, I would have budget for my own server and would like to host the app from my own server.

Answer (score 1):

> After my app has been approved, would it be ok to change the Site URL i.e. the APP would not have its permission revoked by Facebook?

Yes, you can change your app URLs at any time you want. They are not part of what is reviewed.

Permissions that already have been approved will stay approved, changing app URLs does not affect them at all.